# Python (with Tkinter and Selenium Webdriver, created with pyinstaller) app doesn't work on other pc's

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, tkinter, pyinstaller

I created an Python Web Scraper app and it works fine on my pc but sadly not for my friend who I sent it to. I used Pyinstaller to create the application and got two folders, "build" and "dist". I sent the information of both of them to my friend. Still it doesn't work...can anyone help me please?

Stay healty!

Comment: What error messages does your friend see?

Comment: None, it's an app and not code that I sent

Answer (score 2):

Have you added the webdriver binary to pyinstaller?